# Read CSV into R, Parse_Number a Column Only When Values are Present

Tags: r, tidyverse

For this `Rmd` script, a lot of `.csv` files and `.xlsx` files are regularly updated with new data, which is then reflected in the Markdown output. Using basic read commands such as `read_xlsx` & `read_csv` from the `readxl` & `tidyverse` packages, respectively, work well whenever data is present.

To ensure the expense data present is usable for the downstream calculations in the script, I have them set to parse using the following basic format:

`` dat <- read_csv("/PATH/data.csv") %>% mutate(across(c(`Expense`), parse_number)) ``

This keeps me from running into non-numeric type errors down the line. However, this often causes an issue for me when a particular dataset is actually blank for the time being, especially at the beginning of a month or quarter. So I am looking to find a way that I can selectively `parse_number` only when data is actually available.

The current work around I use is having to go in and manually add a `0` under the expense amount to get the calculations to proceed without error, when the file is empty besides headers.

I don't want to do an automatic addition of a zero row to bypass this issue, as there are also counts in the downstream that will need adjusted.

I was hoping that some form of an `if` statement would work:

`if(eval(parse_number)>0, parse_number, 0)`

But I am wholly unsure of doing it within the pipe set-up I have or if there is another logic function that can achieve it instead.

Comment: I cannot test it right now, but does it work when you replace `parse_number` in your function with `function(x){ifelse(length(x) == 0, x, parse_number(x))}`?

Comment: (1) `parse_number(character(0))` returns `numeric(0)`, so empty (0-rows) should still work. Similarly, (2) if a column is all `NA`, `readr::parse_number` should still work without warning/error. If you mean that specific columns may not be present, then `%>% mutate(across(any_of("Expense"), parse_number))` should work conditionally, and do nothing if the column does not yet exist.

Comment: @LeonSamson Well that worked perfectly for what I am looking for. So simple as well. Thank you!

Comment: @r2evans That makes sense, thank you for the response. The comment from Leon resolved for my issue. Thanks for the reminder on `any_of` though, that will probably be handy later on.

Answer (score 0):

Per @leonsamson simple answer, `function(x){ifelse(length(x) == 0, x, parse_number(x))}`, inplace of the `parse_number`:

```
dat <- read_csv("/PATH/data.csv") %>% 
    mutate(across(c(`Expense`), function(x){ifelse(length(x) == 0, x, parse_number(x))}))
```

Yields the correct behavior desired, allowing for the blank dataset to work seamlessly without manual manipulation.